# How can I check the syntax of another PHP script in PHP before it is include()'d

Tags: php, syntax, parse-server

In PHP I am making a kind of bot which dynamically includes a few different PHP files. Since these PHP files may change, I would like the files to be checked for syntax/parse errors before the include() or require() is run. Would this be possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the php executeable with the -l argument from the command line. you can do that using a system call, or shell_exec

Comment: Thanks. I am assuming that there is no more efficient way of achieving this, since I've noticed that the exec("php -l {$file}"); pauses the script for a second.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/php_check_syntax is your help. Check the examples !

Comment: Note:

For technical reasons, this function is deprecated and removed from PHP. Instead, use php -l somefile.php from the commandline.